# Why does Perl complain "can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call"?

Tags: perl

I have *index.pl* and *subs.pl*. When I run the program, the user inserts the date of birth and then it is passed to the `getage()` subroutine in *subs.pl*, which has many subroutines.
`getage()` than implicitly calls another subroutine called `validate()` which validates the date entered by user.

When I run the *index.pl* and the user enters the date as `03-04-2005`, the following error comes out:

> can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call at subs.pl line 85, <> line 1

At 85th line of *subs.pl* I have:

```
list(my $val,my @value) = validate($dob);
```

`validate()` returns a message and the `date($dob)` which is sent from `getage()`.

Some code from validate():

```
sub validate {
    my $dob = shift;
    my $error;
    my @test;
    @test = split("-",$dob);
    if (!@test) {
        $error = "date separator should be - ";
        return ($error,@test);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: You are going to have to give us more code to help us be able to answer you. For one what does Validate return. In addition what is 'list'.

Comment: @Karya got the solution list was the problem i thought list would 'list' the returned value. REMOVING word 'list' did the trick..anyways question is modified , thanks

Answer (score 4):

The solution seems to be:

```
my ($val, @value) = validate($dob);
```

based on my intuitive understanding of what that code intended - but I can't be certain till you provide some more context (what does `validate()` return, what does `list()` mean?)

If you meant list() as a means to force $val and @value into a list, you merely need to enclose both in parenthesis: `($val, @value)` to do that

Comment: FYI `list()` is the PHPism for destructuring list assignment.

Answer (score 2):

An lvalue is a variable you can modify.  (one that can be on the left side of an assignment, hence the name).  In most circumstances, a value returned by a sub is *not* one you can modify.

In your example, you are attempting exactly that: assigning the return value of `validate($dob)` to the nonmodifiable return value of `list($val, @value)`.

Answer (score 0):

in line

```
list(my $val,my @value) = validate($dob);
```

remove 'list' and it works fine

ie

```
(my $val,my @value) = validate($dob);
```

thanks to *Kayra* and others who answered

Comment: the `my` would normally be outside the parens:  `my($val, @value) = validate($dob);`